# Trying to send data from JS to PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am trying send some data from JavaScript to PHP, but it seems I'm not doing it wrong. I am using reverse geocoding to get the location name of a specific marker on google maps, this works just fine. However, I need that particular data on the PHP-side.

This is what my script looks like, **var markerLocation** is the variable I'm trying to get across (js/map_article.js):

```
// Reverse geocoding
function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) 
{   
    result.forEach(function(entry) {
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(entry.lat), lng: parseFloat(entry.lng)};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status)
        {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                if (results[1])
                {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map
                        });
                    infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);

                    var markerLocation = results[1].formatted_address;

                    // Send the adress back to php
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'article.php',
                        data: {markerLocation : markerLocation},
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            alert("success!");
                        }
                    });

                } 
                else 
                {
                    window.alert('No results found');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

And this is what the PHP (article.php) looks like:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id=$id";
    $result = db_select($sql);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // pass PHP variable declared above to JavaScript variable
    var result = <?php echo json_encode($result) ?>;
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/map_article.js"></script>

<body>

<?php

    // Is the AJAX-data coming across?
    if(isset($_POST['markerLocation']))
    {
        echo "<p>".$_POST['markerLocation']."</p>"; 
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "<p>It did not work..</p>";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The Alert message "success!" does show, but the variable $_POST['markerLocation'] is still undefined. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where do you get undefined? In the success handler of AJAX print the data you receive from article.php and check

Comment: alert("success! "+markerLocation); works aswell. The $_POST['markerLocation'] returns as undefined.

Comment: put alert(data). markerLocation is local variable. you need to verify that server is returning you result

Comment: are you calling article.php directly from browser? in that case yes it is undefined because you are sending GET request from browser

Comment: Check if you don't have error in php because `$_GET['id']` is not defined.

Comment: I'm not quite following. The AJAX call is made from the Javascript so it is locally. I need to send var markerLocation back to the server-side (article.php).

Comment: $_GET['id'] is not the issue, i stripped some irrelevant code (that does not affect the issue) to make it more readable, I just want to transfer markerLocation to the php-side.

Comment: Maybe you're using old version of php, try `$HTTP_POST_VARS`

Comment: No, I use plenty of POST variables in other places within this project.

Comment: Create empty php file with `echo json_encode($_POST);` to see what's send via post request, maybe you have typo in your post variable.